# Use of setupcontroller in ember.js route?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js, frontend

Do routes actually need to use setupcontroller() to load model to templete? What is the use of setupcontroller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, yes, the `setupController` hook is where the actual data from the `model` hook is set to the `controller` instance of the current route from which the template layer can access the data. However, you **don't need to do this in every route of your app** as this is the default behaviour ([implementation](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/@ember/-internals/routing/lib/system/route.ts#L1287)) of the framework.

If this behaviour is enough for you, there is no need to define this hook in your route. In case, you need to do some other operations before the page loads, you can use this hook.

for more info, here is the [official API documentation](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.18/classes/Route/methods/setupController?anchor=setupController) which explains with an example.